# Prove that the matrix A is positive definite.

Tags: matrices, representation-theory

A matrix $A$ is defined as:
\begin{equation}
A := \sum_{g\space \epsilon\space G}{{D}^{\dagger}(g)D(g)}
\end{equation}
Where the $D(g)$ are representations matrices of the finite group $G$ on a unitary vector space $V$. I have already proven that it is Hermitian and is an invariant operator; i.e.:
\begin{equation}
A = {A}^{\dagger},
\end{equation}
\begin{equation}
{D}^{\dagger}(g)AD(g) = A
\end{equation}
for all $g$ belonging to $G$. I have now to prove that it is positive definite. Any hints would be appreciated. Also, sorry if my use of LaTeX is somehow wrong, it's my first time using it.

Comment: $D(g)$ is invertible, methinks?

Comment: @DanielFischer, yes, representation matrices are all invertible. From that it can be easily seen that none if their eigenvalues can be zero, but that's as far as I have gone.

Comment: $x^\dagger Ax = \sum x^\dagger D^\dagger(g)D(g)x = \sum \lVert D(g)x\rVert^2$.

Comment: Heh, I think that answers it. Don't know how I missed that. Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From the definition of $A$, we obtain that

$$x^\dagger A x = \sum_{g\in G} x^\dagger D^\dagger(g) D(g)x = \sum_{g\in G} \lVert D(g)x\rVert^2$$

for every $x\in V$. Since the $D(g)$ are invertible, $\lVert D(g)x\rVert^2 > 0$ for $x\neq 0$ and $g\in G$, hence it follows that $x^\dagger A x > 0$ for $x\neq 0$, i.e. $A$ is positive definite.